# How to get map array by filter spesific in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, filter

I want to get value of filter array. cause array is dynamic index position
i have response json like below

```
{
   "plus_code" : {
      "compound_code" : "589V+GM Kasihan, Bantul Regency, Special Region of Yogyakarta, Indonesia",
      "global_code" : "6P4G589V+GM"
   },
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "11",
               "short_name" : "11",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Jalan Madukismo",
               "short_name" : "Jl. Madukismo",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Padokan Kidul",
               "short_name" : "Padokan Kidul",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_5", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Tirtonirmolo",
               "short_name" : "Tirtonirmolo",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_4", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Kecamatan Kasihan",
               "short_name" : "Kec. Kasihan",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_3", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Bantul",
               "short_name" : "Bantul",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Daerah Istimewa Yogyakarta",
               "short_name" : "Jogja",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Indonesia",
               "short_name" : "ID",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "55184",
               "short_name" : "55184",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJtwRkSdcHTCwRhfStG-dNe-M",
         "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

for example i want get value of 'administrative_area_level_3'. but that key not always in that index then i want filter by the key 'administrative_area_level_3'

Comment: where is the code?

Comment: What you can do is convert Json to array and loop through the array and use if statements separately for all your filter types and handel the filter logic there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use iterations in the "address_components" list and then match the values in the "types" that contain administrative_area_level_3. for example :

```
foreach ($json['results'][0]['address_components'] as $value) {
  if(in_array("administrative_area_level_3", $value['types'])){
    $data = $value;
    break;
  }
}

print_r($data);
```